# Similarity between two matrices with distinct sizes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to choose M rows/columns of the NxN matrix that are most similar to the MxM matrix where $M \ll N$.

In my case, both matrices are distance matrices based on separate scales, so they are symmetric, hollow, and positive. I tried iteratively removing the least similar eigenvalues from the NxN matrix, but that did not work well

I was wondering if anyone has recommendations for some base principles I should look at